# PHP-FPM and Nginx rewrite causing download

Tags: nginx, php

I have an Nginx HTTP server with PHP-FPM set up and almost everything works fine.  I want to be able to go to `path/to/file` and it give me `index.php?url=path/to/file`, which it does.  However, it downloads the actual PHP, it won't execute it in the browser.  I'm not sure what is causing this.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sandbox.domain.tld;
    access_log /path/to/domain/log/sandbox.access.log;
    error_log /path/to/domain/log/sandbox.error.log;

    location / {
        root /path/to/sandbox;
        index index.php;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/beta/(.+)$ /beta/index.php?url=$1 break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/sandbox$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the nginx configuration? It sounds like the routing isn't setup to invoke a CGI request when PHP is being accessed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try changing

`rewrite ^/beta/(.+)$ /beta/index.php?url=$1 break;` to

`rewrite ^/beta/(.+)$ /beta/index.php?url=$1 last; break;`

Which should get nginx to re-read the URI and process it accordingly.