# Nginx rewrite some matching rules are not working

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I want to move from these **working** rules

```
location = /contact {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v=contact last; break;
}

location = /terms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v=terms last; break;
}

location = /faq {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v=faq last; break;
}

location = /twitter {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v2=twitter last; break;
}

location = /facebook {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v2=facebook last; break;
}

location = /login {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v2=login last; break;
}

location = /privacy {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?v=privacy last; break;
}
```

to something like this

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  rewrite ^/(contact|privacy|terms|faq)$ /index.php?v=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/(twitter|facebook|login)$ /index.php?v2=$1 last; break;
}
```

But the thing is that 'contact','terms','privacy','twitter','facebook' pages are working correctly but **'privacy' and 'login' pages are throwing 404 error**.

There are no other rewrite rules involving 'login' and 'privacy'

Comment: Suggest open debug log to find out the trace of the two 404 urls.

Comment: @TroyCheng `open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/privacy" failed (2: No such file or directory)` so it is simply not rewriting

Comment: I mean when open debug option, you can trace the rewrite process in error_log, thus you can know how it rewrites and where is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i don't like neither of the methods, it might be working but it's not really the best way to write it, so lets try something different.

```
location *~ ^/(contact|privacy|terms|faq)/?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?v=$1;
}
location *~ ^/(twitter|facebook|login)/?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?v2=$1;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

o and I never heard of a `last; break;` it's probably working only because nginx is ignoring the last part of it, it's either a `last` or a `break`,

Comment: this fails nginx configuration file and also is not the best solution, because in case index.php is not available it will start redirection loop and won`t throw error (only after too many redirects)
And I believe that 'last;' and 'break;' mix is used because 'last;' makes the script to repeat and php to execute, 'break;' ends the current location section [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13981316/1612250](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13981316/1612250)